# How to make android ratingbar show correct number of stars?

Tags: android, layout, ratingbar

I have a ratingbar which should have max value of 10 and step size 1. I need 10 stars to be there. But when I run the app on my galaxy nexus there are only 4 and half stars.
[image]

My 8 rating is on the middle of the last full star.
How can I make android to draw exactly 10 stars?
Or can I make it to go to the second row if there's no space in layout?

Comment: "How can I make android to draw exactly 10 stars?" -- use smaller stars. "Or can I make it to go to the second row if there's no space in layout?" -- I don't believe so.

Comment: CommonsWare, the problem is that small stars are very small on tablets. I was wondering if there's a way to fit 10 stars to the given space..

Comment: AFAIK, `RatingBar` does not scale the drawables based upon available space. It's possible that somebody has written a `FittableRatingBar` (or whatever) that would scale the images to fit the available space. Or, perhaps you could create that yourself, either as a subclass of `RatingBar` or as a fork of `RatingBar`. The same thing holds true for the second-line concept -- that's not in `RatingBar`, but there's nothing stopping someone from creating a `RatingBar` that does.

Comment: CommonsWare ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: the documentation recommends you to use wrap_content for width. to make it smaller you will have to use style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"